# json to javascript array and storing for outside ajax call use

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Hey was hoping for some quick help,

My overall goal is to retrieve a php array and store it into a javascript array using an ajax call. I am new to all of this, so please bear with me.

My ajax call is successful such that it returns the echo json_encode(array); and goes to the success function.

I am confused on how to take json encoded data and store it into a javascript array that I am able to use outside the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myurl.php
        data: {var1: var1, var2:var2},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
          var simplified = JSON.stringify(data);
          console.log(simplified);
          var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + simplified + ']');
        },
    });
```

The console logs gives me;

```
Object {63: Object, 64: Object, 65: Object}
```

and

```
{"63":{"Comment":"tc 1"},"64":{"Comment":"tc 2"},"65":{"Comment":"tc 3"}}
```

respectively.

I would like an array in this form;

```
63
  Comment=>"tc 1"
64
  Comment=>"tc 2"
65 
  Comment=>"tc 3"
```

Thanks for any sort of help!

UPADTE:
Any suggestions on how I would access the created array outside of the ajax call? Everytime I try to, it says it is undefined.

Comment: JSON is already an array, more specifically *an object*.

Comment: Define something like `var anArray;` outside the ajax call and then `anArray = jsonObj;`  in your `success` callback.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the object's property and create an array:

```
var myObj = {
    1: [1, 2, 3],
    2: [4, 5, 6]
};

var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});


console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"63":{"Comment":"tc 1"},"64":{"Comment":"tc 2"},"65":{"Comment":"tc 3"}}');
alert(data[63].Comment); // to access
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hmm I tried to use 'data' outside of the ajax call and it says that it is undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have a `global` variable and assign `data` to it and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` variable is already an object. jQuery internally parsed the JSON into an object. If you want to make it an array, here you go:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: myurl.php
  data: {var1: var1, var2:var2},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data)
  {
    var arr = [];

    $.map(data, function(value) {
      arr.push(value);
    });
  }
});
```

But if you still need the key (you had on server-side) just keep it like that and access it like `data[63]`. Javascript doesn't have associative arrays, here they are objects, semanticaly called array-like objects.